# Custom Menu objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu

I need a help please suggest me,
I want to make something like this menu

[image]

When you press on menu button it will give 5 options to select and also put animation like jumping effect.

I have search around and i found the control similar to fulfill my requirement

https://github.com/ink-spot/UPStackMenu

But in this classes when i change the background of the titles of each item it changes the icon background also, i need similar to exact my screenshot with title only have a black background.

Please help me out.

Comment: I guess you are using instance with background color.

Comment: in their class only one single item we have to set so we can set background color only one item @UmaMadhavi

Comment: Yes they have used custom method so for complete background it is applying.

Comment: So i need only text background not image background. if it is not possible in this classes provide other third party classes if you have i can try that @UmaMadhavi

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary framework. You can write code you to work.
for example:
    //add uiview with options in parentview and hiden this uiview;

```
  UIView *menuView = [UIVIew Alloc]init];  
    menuView.frame = ...;   
    menuView.hidden = YES;  
    //add function showMenuAction for Click Button;  
    -(void)showMenuAction{  
         //now menuView Show And change position to left or other local;  
         CGRect menuViewRect = menuView.frame;  
         menuView.hidden = NO;  
         menuViewRect.origin.x = -200;//for not showing menuView In parent View;  
         menuView.frame = mainViewRect;  
         menuViewRect.x = 0;  
        [uiview animationduration:0.4 animation:^{  
             menuView.frame = menuViewRect;  
        }];  
    }
```

Comment: Did you see that classes and it's animation @afshin?

Comment: I do not use this framework, I have my idea with example

Comment: I use this classes because i want same animation that classes have given @afshin